# Regex to find digits not followed by certain characters

Tags: python, regex

I currently have a text field that contains information about times that are to be used for scheduling purposes. As it is a text field the data is unstructured and is in many different formats. Examples of data include:

- Mon-Wed 6-7:30pm
- Tuesday/Thurs 5:00 - 6:30
- M/T/W 3:30 -7
- F 4-5

As such I am trying to write a parser to turn these into usable data points. I am working on the time components at the moment. In order to structure the data and have the ability to pass it into the `dateutil` parser I want to "fill out" all times. 6 would become 6:00, 7 would become 7:00 etc. To do so I am trying to use the regex expression:

```
reg = re.compile('[\d]([^:]|$)')
```

The idea is to get any digit that either does not have a : after it, or is at the end of the line. However, I realized that this will get too many data points as in the first example it would get the '3' of 7:30 and the 0 of 7:30.

What would be a better way to convert this data to a usable format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it in two-stage manner, harnessing one interesting feature of `re.split`, sample data:

```
line1 = 'Mon-Wed 6-7:30pm'
line2 = 'Tuesday/Thurs 5:00 - 6:30'
line3 = 'M/T/W 3:30 -7'
line4 = 'F 4-5'
```

Function:

```
def add_zeros(line):
    parts = re.split(r'(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})',line)
    parts[::2] = [re.sub(r'(\d{1,2})',r'\1:00',p) for p in parts[::2]]
    return ''.join(parts)
```

Usage:

```
print(add_zeros(line1)) # Mon-Wed 6:00-7:30pm
print(add_zeros(line2)) # Tuesday/Thurs 5:00 - 6:30
print(add_zeros(line3)) # M/T/W 3:30 -7:00
print(add_zeros(line4)) # F 4:00-5:00
```

Explanation:

I give `re.sub` the first argument within the group. `re.split` gives a `list` with odd-indexed elements being *separators*. With the pattern I used in `re.split` the *seperators* are "ready" hours (which do not need zero-padding). I then use `re.sub` on every even-indexed element of list (the non "ready" hours), treating every 1 or 2 digit number as an hour and replacing it with the number followed by `:00`

Comment: Going through it slowly to understand the logic, but it works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you could use a negative lookbehind and negative lookahead `(?<!(:)\d)\d(?!(:|\d))`
https://regex101.com/r/nAQh3e/4
this will pick out the numbers that don't have a digit before or after it and don't already have a `:`

Comment: Unfortunately this fails for stuff like `12-5` or `1-11` as seen here: https://regex101.com/r/nAQh3e/2

Comment: correct! updated to provide support for a digit after the : character...it should work like this

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be much easier to find the incorrect time after replacing the correct time with a placeholder. Then we can correct the incorrect time format and then again substitute the placeholder with actual times

Here is simple implementation, you can tweak this to match your need

```py
import re

texts = ["Mon-Wed 6-7:30pm",
"Tuesday/Thurs 5:00 - 6:30",
"M/T/W 3:30 -7",
"F 4-5",]

def get_placeholder_replacer(replaced_strings):
    def replace_with_placeholder(x):
        replaced_strings.append(x[0])
        return "{}"
    return replace_with_placeholder


ptrn_correct_time = re.compile(r"\d+:\d+")
ptrn_incorrect_time = re.compile(r"\d{1,2}")

for text in texts:
    replaced_strings = []
    placeholder_replacer = get_placeholder_replacer(replaced_strings)
    new_text = ptrn_correct_time.sub(placeholder_replacer,text)
    new_text = ptrn_incorrect_time.sub(lambda x: "{}:00".format(x[0]), new_text)

    print(new_text.format(*replaced_strings))

## Output
# Mon-Wed 6:00-7:30pm
# Tuesday/Thurs 5:00 - 6:30
# M/T/W 3:30 -7:00
# F 4:00-5:00
```